# Execute Get Request every 5 seconds on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to execute an http get request to an api every 5 seconds from my reactjs app, although using the setTimeout function, after the first 5 seconds all the requests are done.

```
getPerson = (url) => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      let person = {};
      person.id = response.data.id;
      person.name = response.data.name;
      person.type = response.data.type;
      this.state.persons.push(person);
      this.setState({ persons: this.state.persons });
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
  for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    this.getPerson(this.apiUrl + i);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("waiting for the next call.");
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Including the http request into the setTimeout function gives me an execution error

Comment: 1. you need `setInterval` 2. you need to move the `getPerson()` call into the function passed to `setInterval` 3. you should change your API so you can request all person data with a single request 4. you're mutating `this.state`, which you aren't supposed to do 5. if you must use multiple requests, you should use `Promise.all()` 6. you keep pushing new persons to the state, so if you fix the current issue, your persons array will have 10 elements, then 20, then 30, etc. Is this really what you intend?

Comment: Regarding the comment you posted: use `setTimeout(() => { /* code here */ }, i * 5000);` This should solve both the `this` issue and the timing issue.

Comment: why not web socket?

Answer (score 0):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let i = 0;
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i<11) {
        this.getPerson(this.apiUrl + i);
        i++;
        console.log("waiting for the next call.");
      }
      else {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }

    }, 5000);
  }
```

You should use `setInterval()` for that purpose, not `setTimeout()`

**EDIT**: In case you somehow don't have access to `this` in `setInterval()`, even though you should because it's an arrow function, you can use a workaround

`let that = this` and then call your method with `that.getPerson(that.apiUrl + i);`

Comment: I don't think OP wants to wait 5 seconds in between two persons; as far as I understand the question they want to load all persons, then wait 5 seconds, then load all persons again, etc.

Comment: @ChrisG Maybe, yes. The question is not clear as it is now. What gave me the idea he wants this solution is "although using the setTimeout function, after the first 5 seconds all the requests are done." which implies he doesn't want all the requests done after 5 seconds.

Comment: I want to load a person every 5 seconds, the problem of that code is I can´t access to "this" object inside setInterval function so I can´t perform changes on my state object.

Comment: @user3034457 Why you can't access "this" when it's an arrow function? Even if that is case, you can always do `let that = this` and then use `that.apiUrl`

Comment: @user3034457 I have updated the answer. Can you please try it now?

Comment: sorry Mirakurun, your answer didn´t work either, having same problem accessing this object from setInterval() function.

Answer (score 0):

Still having the problem to access "this" object from inside anonymous block function.

```
  getPerson = (url) => {
axios.get(url)
  .then(response => {
    let person = {};
    person.id = response.data.id;
    person.name = response.data.name;
    this.state.loadedPersons.push(person);
    this.setState({ loadedPersons: this.state.loadedPersons });
  });}


componentDidMount() {
for (var j = 1; j < 152; j++) {
  this.getPerson(this.apiUrl + j);
}
let i = 1;
let that = this.state;
console.log("That out of in interval:" + that);
let interval = setInterval(function (that) {
  console.log("That in interval:" + that);
  if ((i<152))
    that.persons.push(that.loadedPersons[i]);
    i++;
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }

}, 5000);
```

}

Console output:

That out of interval: [Object  object]

That in interval: undefined